# Add unique items to recyclerView from geoQuery

Tags: java, android, geofire

I created an app that shows items of users near me.

I find the people who near me by using `geoQuery` and if they are near me, I search in the database what items they have and I populate a `RecyclerView` with them.

I do so by using:

```
List<DiscoverItems> items = new ArrayList<>();

GeoQuery geoQuery = geoFire.queryAtLocation(new GeoLocation(Lat, Lon), Radius);
geoQuery.addGeoQueryEventListener(new GeoQueryEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onKeyEntered(String key, GeoLocation location) {

        String UserID = key;

        if (!UserID.equals(auth.getUid())) {
            db.collection("Users").document(UserID).collection("MyItems").get().addOnCompleteListener(task_count -> {
                if (task_count.isSuccessful()) {
                    for (DocumentSnapshot document_near : task_count.getResult()) {
                        items.add(new DiscoverItems(document_near.getString("ItemID")));
                    }

                }
            });
        }

        discoverItemAdapter = new DiscoverItemAdapter(items, listener);
        rv_NearMeItems.setAdapter(discoverItemAdapter);

    }

    @Override
    public void onKeyExited(String key) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onKeyMoved(String key, GeoLocation location) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onGeoQueryReady() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onGeoQueryError(DatabaseError error) {

    }
});
```

However, my problem is if some users have the same item, because then it will appear twice in the recyclerView while I had liked it to have unique items.

Is there any solution where I can first check my items list for duplicate and only then to add them?

I tried to do the following:

```
List<DiscoverItems> items= new ArrayList<>();
Set<DiscoverItems> itemkset = new HashSet<>();

GeoQuery geoQuery = geoFire.queryAtLocation(new GeoLocation(Lat, Lon), Radius);
geoQuery.addGeoQueryEventListener( new GeoQueryEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onKeyEntered(String key, GeoLocation location) {

        String UserID = key;

        if (!UserID.equals( auth.getUid() )) {
            db.collection( "Users" ).document( UserID ).collection( "MyItems" ).get().addOnCompleteListener( task_count -> {
                if (task_count.isSuccessful()) {
                    for (DocumentSnapshot document_near : task_count.getResult()) {
                        itemset.add( new DiscoverItems( document_near.getString( "ItemID" ) ) );
                    }
                }
            } );
        }
        List<DiscoverItems> itemsWithoutDuplicates = new ArrayList<>(new HashSet<>(itemset));
        for (DiscoverItems item: itemsWithoutDuplicates){
            items.add(item);
        }
    discoverItemAdapter = new DiscoverItemAdapter(items, listener);
    rv_NearMeItems.setAdapter(discoverItemAdapter);
    }
```

But it doesn't work since if for example, I have 2 users, `onKeyEntered` will be called twice. For the first user it will add to `itemset` let say 4 items which are not identical and everything will be ok. Then it will call the second user which will add also 3 items to itemset which are not identical and it will be ok.

Am I missing something?
Because with the code above I'm getting multiple items.

Thank you

Comment: Base on which field or criteria you can say that "objects are that same"?

Comment: based on document_near.getString( "ItemID" )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the complexity of your objects, but you can try change from `List<>` int to `Set<>`. In general `Set` is collection that contains **no duplicate elements** (e.g. base on theirs hashcode).

## 1) Objects comparing

First of all you have to override `equals()` and `hashCode()` in `DiscoverItems` class to work with hash-based collections (like `HashSet`).

You can generate those method in Android Studio and choose base on which fields you can say that "those two objects are that same". Sometimes it's not necessary to compare all of the fields (you can use for example only name or some ID).

You your case, you have to compare this field which you are passing to constructor of `DiscoverItems` class. It can look like there:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    if (this == object) return true;
    if (object == null || getClass() != object.getClass()) return false;
    DiscoverItems that = (DiscoverItems) object;
    return Objects.equals(itemID, that.itemID);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(itemID);
}
```

## 2)  Collection

So change from:

```
List<DiscoverItems> items = new ArrayList<>();
```

in to:

```
Set<DiscoverItems> items = new HashSet<>();
```

When you need checking in one place, you can convert:

```
List ---> Set ---> List
```

for example:

```
Set<DiscoverItems> set = new HashSet<>(items);

if (items.size() == set.size()) {
    // No duplicates, use original list
} else {
    // Duplicates removed, use new list
    List<DiscoverItems> itemsWithoutDuplicates = new ArrayList<>(set);
}
```

or without extra condition:

```
Set<DiscoverItems> set = new HashSet<>(items);
List<DiscoverItems> itemsWithoutDuplicates = new ArrayList<>(set);
```

or as one-liner:

```
List<DiscoverItems> itemsWithoutDuplicates = new ArrayList<>(new HashSet<>(items));
```

## Hint

You should name your class `DiscoverItem` not `DiscoverItems`. Because it is representing ONE item, not many.

Comment: Is there any way I can test my List for duplicates and then set my recyclerView? because this adapter is used many times in the app and only here I need to check for duplicates.

Comment: The thing is that one user wont have same items so I need to use this HashSet between the users but I cant since it doesnt pass any data between the calls from what I see

Comment: I do not understand why "you cant". You are asking about "removing duplicates" and `HashSet` (after proper implementation `equals()` and `hashCode()`) is doing that.

Comment: It took me a while to understand what you meant. Thank you mate